# What's the difference between 'vm' and 'virtual-machine' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I see there's separate [vm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vm) and [virtual-machines](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machines) tags. What's the difference? Should they be made synonyms?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear like there is any difference.  I have [proposed an alias](https://serverfault.com/tags/virtual-machines/synonyms). When someone has some spare time, they should retag the questions.

Comment: I've retagged a bunch, but I don't want to flood the front page, so I'll let it be for now

Comment: ok I merged and approved tons!